# How to store the value in the JLabel without it resetting each time the JButton is activated?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm creating a program that when you enter a value greater than 18 it adds one to the `JLabel` however each time I click the button the program resets back to 1 instead of adding an additional one.

For example if I enter another value greater than 18, the `JLabel` should add an additional one so the total is two...

This is my code:

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()); // gets the value from the button click

if(age >= 18){ // determines if it is greater then 18
     int totalOne = 0;
     totalOne = totalOne + 1;
     String totalAgeOne = Integer.toString(totalOne);
     jLabel3.setText(totalAgeOne); // sets the jlabel to One
}else{
     int totalTwo = 0;
     totalTwo = totalTwo + 1;
     String totalAgeTwo = Integer.toString(totalTwo);
     jLabel5.setText(totalAgeTwo);    
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It seems like `int totalOne = 0;` should be `int totalOne = age;`, but for more than vague theories, see my first comment. BTW - this seems better suited to a `JSpinner` instead of a `JLabel` / `JButton` combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the current value of the JLabel, and then add one to it.

```
jLabel3.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(jLabel3.getText())+1));
```

Currently, your variable `totalOne` and `totalTwo` reset to the value of 0 ever time it runs through the conditional statement because they are local variables.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I understand the logic however when I put your code into my code an error occurs -  actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion???